# Mostrar registros aleatorios de MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un pequeño proyecto donde tengo una tabla de preguntas en mysql 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero mediante php tengo que generar 5 preguntas aleatorias de esta tabla sin que se repitan, todo esto desde php. Llevo dándole vueltas mucho y solo he llegado a mostrar solo las preguntas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Si en vez de dejar una captura del código lo copias y pegas será más fácil para quien pueda ayudarte hacerlo :)

Answer (score 4):

Tu consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM preguntas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

- `RAND()` Es una función que retorna un valor de tipo flotante entre 0 y 1.0, la usaremos para seleccionar valores aleatorios.
- `LIMIT 5` Usamos este parámetro para indicar que de los valores regresados de manera aleatoria, solo tome 5 de ellos decartando los demás.

Comment: necesito hacerlo mediante php, generando numeros aleatorios. esa consulta me funciona pero devo hacer el uso de rnd en php